# Does Clang/C2 use the same semantic analysis & AST as Clang/LLVM?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

I think Clang/C2 uses the Clang frontend which contains semantic analysis & AST, and just replaced the LLVM codegen with C2.
But strangely there's some inconsistency between Clang/C2 & Clang/LLVM.

For example, given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int)
{
    std::cout << "int!\n";
}

template<class T>
void fun(T i)
{
    f(i);
}

void f(float)
{
    std::cout << "float!\n";
}

int main()
{
    fun(5.f);
    return 0;
}
```

The standard behavior is to select the `int` overload. G++ & Clang/LLVM give me the correct result.
OTOH, MSVC is known to lack of 2-phrase lookup, so it selects the `float` overload. What strange is, Clang/C2, which should use Clang frontend and thus have 2-phrase lookup, also give me the same result as MSVC.

Is the normal semantic analysis & AST not used in Clang/C2, or does it mimic the MSVC on purpose here?

Comment: So MS has glued their great big complex compiler machinery together with Clang's great big compiler machinery.   It wouldn't surprise me if MS tried to bend the Clang machinery to match what the MS compiler does.  It should surprise you if they ever get them to completely agree.

Comment: Clang has several options that influence this: `-fms-extensions`(on in a default VS Clang/C2 project), `-fms-compatibility`(off by default) and `-fdelayed-template-parsing`(on by default). The last one very closely reproduces the "1-phase" lookup of MSVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

melak47 is correct. We've been working on getting the defaults fixed up for Clang/C2. Our intention is to turn off all of the MSVC compatibility options, but we're doing that incrementally. The Clang/C2 compiler uses the same Clang front end as Clang/LLVM and should (eventually) behave as Clang/LLVM behaves.

So to answer your question directly, yes Clang/C2 uses the same semantic analysis and AST as Clang/LLVM. We didn't modify Clang except to have it hook up to C2. (Small lie: we also have it generate debug information, but that's being pushed back to the Clang trunk.)

As for the other comment, Microsoft has no need to create a Clang that "bends to match what the MS compiler does". The Clang-cl project does that. See, for example, the last slide here: http://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-04/PDFs/Talks/clang-cl.pdf